# Recursive call complexity

Tags: python, recursion, complexity-theory

I have some difficulty proving the complexity of these two recursive codes. I have some intuition about them. I think the first one is O(n), and the second is O(nlogn). these are the codes:

```
def max_v1(lst):
    if len(lst)== 1:
        return lst[0]
    return max(lst[0], max_v1(lst[1:]))


def max_v2(lst):
    if len(lst)== 1:
        return lst[0]
    l = max_v2(lst[:len(lst)//2])
    r = max_v2(lst[len(lst)//2:])
    return max(l, r)
```

Comment: This really depends on whether you're talking about the *algorithm*, or the *implementation*.  The first one's implementation is actually O(N*N)! in implementation, but the algorithm could be coded recursively almost identically to that in O(N).  The reason is because in python, a list slice (`lst[1:]`) is actually an `O(N-1)` operation in itself.

Comment: @mgilson: Careful with that exclamation point. Although it's outside the parentheses, it still looks a lot like a factorial.

Comment: @user2357112 -- Fair enough.  I was putting it in there for **emphasis**.  Unfortunately, my 5 minute edit window is now gone ... :-/

Comment: Im talking about time complexity for a list in length N. I used a recursion tree and found out that the depth is O(n), now because of the slicing it does each level O(n-1) or just O(1)?

Comment: @user2751595 slicing is a *linear time* operation, not constant time. You are doing `O(n)` work for each of the `O(n)` levels. In particular the complexity of the first would be approximately `O(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ...+ n-1) = O(n(n-1)/2) = O(n^2)`. The second is `O(nlog(n))` because you are doing `O(n)` work for each of the `O(log(n))` levels. If you used `start` and `end` pointers both solutions would be `O(n)`, but the second one would use less stack depth, while the first one would fail for lists longer than `1000` (due to the default recursion limit).

Answer (score 4):

```
def max_v1(lst):
    if len(lst)== 1:
        return lst[0]
    return max(lst[0], max_v1(lst[1:]))
```

`max(...)` is O(2), which is called once per `max_v1` function call, but the slicing is O(N) for each function call.  Hence, we get O(2*N*N) = O(N<sup>2</sup>).

```
def max_v2(lst):
    if len(lst)== 1:
        return lst[0]
    l = max_v2(lst[:len(lst)//2])
    r = max_v2(lst[len(lst)//2:])
    return max(l, r)
```

`max_v2` is called twice per `max_v2` function call, and each time is passed half of the `list`, resulting in O(2*N*log(N)), due to the slicing and function calls.  `max()` is called once per function call and therefore gives a total of N*O(2) = O(N).  Hence, we get O(N+2*N*log(N)) = O(N*log(N)).

Comment: As just two elements are being passed to max(...), I think 'max', in first example, should take O(2) i.e. constant time. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @sk4x0r Thank you, you are correct. I made edits and fixed it.  The first is still O(N^2), though.